# Is UPNP supported on QT?

Tags: qt, upnp, gupnp

I am trying to venture into the UPNP programming. However, I don't know how to use the upnp library on Linux.  I don't like the gnu - UPNP stuffs. It confuses me a lot. However, I can give a try if I can find some simple examples on either QT-UPNP or G-UPNP. Please do share some simple examples on it. My preference is QT. In case, QT doesn't support UPNP, please suggest some other alternative examples. I tried with libupnp version, but their example code crashed with a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QT does not include UPnP functionality (as a Google search must have told you). I think it's fair to say that there is no QT-based UPnP library that is close to being as stable and complete as GUPnP is.

GUPnP has examples included in the source code, starting from simple [light switch](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gupnp/tree/examples) to more [complex tools](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gupnp-tools/tree/src).

Answer (score 0):

Qt doesn't integrate any UPnP module.
But there are some projects which tried to implement UPnP for Qt, like :

- Brisa
- Herqq
- [QUPnP](https://code.google.com/p/qupnp/)

But these are a bit old and not really stable

To see others UPnP implementations, please visit the [UPnP forum website](http://upnp.org/sdcps-and-certification/resources/sdks/)